# Where the data related to firefox urlbar.autoFill is stored?

Tags: macos, firefox, autocomplete

> Attention! This question is **not** about auto filling the forms
>   and/or passwords!

In firefox (just like chrome) when I type in `s` in the address bar, it automatically fill the rest to `superuser.com`.

What I want is to modify some of these urls entries (e.g. replace `superuser.com` with `http://superuser.com/tags`).

My question is, where is(are) the file (files) storing these data in `Mac OS X` and `Ubuntu`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autocomplete popup of the urlbar is populated through a set of queries to the Places database. That's the places.sqlite file, located at your profile directory.

I would advise against editing it, unless you 're sure you know what you 're doing.

Instead, bookmark `http://superuser.com/tags` and set `s` as its keyword.